# Find temp folder for user Network Service?

Tags: .net, sql-server, windows

I'm trying to write a wrapper to help our customers restore a SQL Server database. By default SQL Server runs as user Network Service which has very limited permissions. Our customers are sometimes confused that they can't just point to a backup file in any location and restore it.

I want to copy the file from the location they choose to a temp location that SQL Server can access but I'm having a hard time finding a location.  I can't just call Path.GetTempPath() because that gives me the user's temp which SQL Server can't access.

Is there a folder I can retrieve that will always work?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The temp folder for the Network Service account is located here:

> %Windir%\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp

On Windows XP/2003 the network service profile is located in the general user profile directory. On a German machine it is here:

> C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\NetworkService\Lokale Einstellungen\Temp

On an English computer it would be here:

> C:\Documents and Settings\NetworkService\Local Settings\Temp

You can find the path to the profile on all Windows versions by querying this registry value:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-20\ProfileImagePath

That does not give you the localized name of "Local Settings" on XP/2003, though.

By default, Administrators can write to the network service profile. Using it's temp folder for your purpose should be perfectly OK.

Comment: That looks like what I'm after. I'll try that.

Comment: Updated my answer to include XP, too.

Comment: For the `Local System` account, it can be found at `%WINDIR%\Temp` on Windows 2008 and later.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows Vista and above

1. System Account (`NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`)
   `C:\Windows\TEMP`
2. Network Service (`NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`) 
   `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp`
3. Local Service (`NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE`)
   `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Temp`

Comment: The System account actually stores a profile in the following folder and a temp folder may exist there as well. (It's frequently a store for .NET update temp files.)
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\

Answer (score 0):

Why not just give NETWORK_SERVICE permission to a specific folder and tell the users to place the backup files there?

Or just run:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [master] TO DISK='master.bak'
GO
```

from SSMS and see where the file gets written to.

Comment: I don't want to have to customize each customers system by changing permissions. System Admins don't like us telling them to add permissions to folders and I rather not do that unless I have no other choice.