# Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server

I'm trying to establish a linked server from `SQL Server 2008 R2` to an `Access database`. The `Access database` is not password protected. As I have seen in other posts ([specifically this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362108/cannot-initialize-the-data-source-object-of-ole-db-provider-msdasql-for-linked)), this is usually due to the current user not having access to the Temp folder inside the NetworkService folder. Since we are running this in `Windows Server 2008`, the directory structure is quite different than what most are eluding to. I have allowed access to every temp folder in the `"root:\Documents and Settings\" directory`, and to no avail.

This is the procedure I am using to add the linked server:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
@server = N'OS_Access', 
@provider = N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
@srvproduct = N'',
@datasrc = N'C:\RTBData\Data\OS.mdb';
GO
```

It creates the linked server with no problem, but I am not able to view the tables/views of the database. Likewise, my ASP.NET application cannot access it either.

I have tried both `ACE and JET(64-bit)`(by installing the Data Connectivity Components for Office), and they both do not work. I have also tried configuring the ACE provider with `"Dynamic Parameter"` and `"Allow InProcess"` to true.

Additionally, I tried upping the memory usage by the `MSSQLSERVER services` by adding `"-g512;`" in front of `"startup parameters"` string in SQL configuration manager to rule out memory issues.

If anyone could shed some light on this that would be fantastic! Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I logged into SQL using the sa account, and I was able to view the linked server. My current user account has full permissions in SQL server, so I am unsure of what the difference is between the accounts. Maybe I gave permissions to the wrong `Temp` folder, in which the sa account (being built-in) has access to. If someone could point me in the right direction here, that would be great, and I think it would also help a lot of other people.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986756/cannot-initialize-the-data-source-object-of-ole-db-provider-microsoft-ace-oledb/33609865#33609865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by disabling UAC within the control panel. I am unsure what changes this made, but it might help others!

Answer (score 2):

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'AllowInProcess' , 1
GO
EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'DynamicParameters' , 1
GO
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Name & Location of DB';;, [TableName])
```