# Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)"

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

When I run the following commmands in SQL Server 2012

```
 exec sp_configure 'Advanced', 1 RECONFIGURE
 exec sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1 RECONFIGURE
 EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
 EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1

 SELECT * INTO dbo.Normalization FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=c:\_sandbox\Consolidations.xlsx','SELECT * FROM [Codes and Values$]')
```

I get this error

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider
>   "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the provider installed?  The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider isn't there by default and so if you haven't installed it the it won't be able to be initialised.

Have a look in SQL management studio in Server Objects -> Linked Servers -> Providers and see if it is listed.

If not, you need to install the Microsoft Access Database Engine (either x86 or x64 depending on your SQL server install) which will install the provider for you.

Download the software here:

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Comment: what about If i have an office 32bit and sql server 64 bits?

Comment: You need to download the correct version for SQL server to use, which as I have found out previously on a dev machine involves uninstalling the other office components if they don't match

Comment: @steoleary, I am having the same problem but I have the provider listed on the path you said. Here is my query `SELECT * FROM
OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'X:\path\filename.mdb',' password')` Where did I go wrong? Before that, I executed this `Exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
 
Exec sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'AllowInProcess' , 1; 
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'DynamicParameters' , 1;
GO`

Comment: Off the top of my head I can't remember the exact syntax, but I do remember that when selecting data from an access DB, you have to supply the query in the parameters sent to openrowset, something like this SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',';Data Source=X:\path\filename.mdb;','SELECT * from table') otherwise openrowset won't be able to return any data.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error with access database. I was using this syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','DataSource=D:\test.mdb')...[MyTableName]
```

Then I come to know that 'DataSource' should be 'Data Source'.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Data Source=D:\test.mdb')...[MyTableName]
```

It works in my case.