# Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "LinkedServer"

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, sql-server-2008-r2

I’ve created a .NET website that uses SQL Server 2008 R2 with a linked server to an Access database (.mdb).  The linked server works, I can browse to the .mdb tables and query the tables in SQL Server.  When the website is run using Visual Studio, all tables are accessed without a problem.   When the website is run using IIS, I get an error when it tries to select records from the Access database. The SQL server tables are fine.  The error is “Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "[Name of linked server]".  (Which is also the name of the database.)

Here are the details in no particular order:

- Windows Server 2008 Enterprise 64-bit
- SQL Server 2008 R2 64 – bit
- IIS7
- The access database has an "Access 2000 File Format" (seen when
  the file is opened in Access 2010)
- Office is not installed on the server (including Access)
- IIS is set up with Anonymous Authentication using the IUSR account.
- The IUSR account has been given full control over the directory where
  the .mdb database resides.
- Views are created from the Access tables and the website accesses the
  Views
- This is the connection string:

  add name="ApplicationServices" 
  connectionString="data source=[server];
  Integrated Security=SSPI;
  Initial Catalog=[SQL server db];" 
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

In SQL Server, this is the code that was used to set up the Linked Server

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
   @server = N'LinkedServer', 
   @provider = N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
   @srvproduct = N'OLE DB Provider for ACE',
   @datasrc = N'C:\RTS_NEW\RTS\App_Data\Data\AccessDatase.mdb';
GO
```

Under Linked Servers -> Providers, the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider has had the following items enabled under Properties

- Dynamic Parameter
- Allow inprocess
- Disallow adhoc access

This is interesting.  When I run the website through Visual Studio and it hits the SQL Server database (without hitting the Access database), an .ldb file is created in the same directory as the .mdb file.   When I browse to the same page in IIS, a .lbl is not created.  No ldb file is created either when I go to a page that accesses the Access database.  Could IIS be putting the file in a different directory that does not have permissions set for IUSR?  Where would I find that directory?

I’ve restarted SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) with no effect.

Can anyone see what I’m overlooking?  Or give me an idea of where to look next?  Any help is appreciated!

---

**Solution**

Using ProcMon, I was able to tell which directories needed permissions set.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

I found adding the AppPool account to the "Group or user name" of a folder in order to give it permission a bit tricky.  Here's a good explantion:

[IIS7 Permissions Overview - ApplicationPoolIdentity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334216/iis7-permissions-overview-applicationpoolidentity)

Comment: In case anyone else has the problem, the directory which needs the permissions set is the temp directory for the SQL Server user, for example `C:\Users\-sqlserveruser-\AppData\Local\Temp`.

Comment: might also give some idea. an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986756/cannot-initialize-the-data-source-object-of-ole-db-provider-microsoft-ace-oledb/33609865#33609865