# Using dynamic sql in openrowset produces error

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

I need to create a stored procedure that gets a path as a parameter and inserts from file into table via OPENROWSET command.

After lots of searching and trying, I learned that `OPENROWSET` does not
support parameters and thus needs to be called with dynamic SQL.

That is the part that doesn't work, it shows me a strange error.

It could be caused by the `OPENROWSET` not accepting the string parameter
but - I saw many code snippets that are built similarly and users say they work.

Please help me understand what I'm missing here and how do I make this work?

Here is my code:

```
Declare @string varchar(MAX) = 'C:\Users\akoga_000\Desktop\test1.xlsx'
DECLARE @sqlString AS varchar(MAX)=

'insert into gameIt_DBSummer.dbo.tblUser 
select * from openrowset(
''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
 ''EXCEL 12.0;DataBase=''
 '+cast(@string as varchar(max))+'
 '';Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'',
 ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]''
)';

EXEC (@sqlString)
```

//I tried also with EXEC sp_executesql and a nvarchar variable among other options

Here is the error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near 'C:'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting that error because you need double extra '' character surrounding the path (@string variable). Try this:

```
Declare @string varchar(MAX) = 'C:\Users\akoga_000\Desktop\test1.xlsx'
DECLARE @sqlString AS varchar(MAX)=
'insert into gameIt_DBSummer.dbo.tblUser 
select * from openrowset(
''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
 ''EXCEL 12.0;DataBase=''''
 '+@string+'
 '''';Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'',
 ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]''
)';
select @sqlString
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I did as you suggested. and it semms that It solved the syntax error BUT now I am getting another error:  OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only.".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

The file and the database  are not read only....Any ideas?Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267224/the-ole-db-provider-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-for-linked-server-null