# OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Unspecified error"

Tags: sql-server, excel, oledb

I am trying to open excel file in SQL server using OLEDB provider, it gives the eroor beloW:

```
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Unspecified error"
```

notes that i have called the below

```
USE [master]
 EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'

, N'AllowInProcess', 1

   GO


   EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'

, N'DynamicParameters', 1

  GO
```

Comment: open it in which way? Can you just use SSMS?

Comment: Make sure file is closed and look through this pretty similar if not identical question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267224/the-ole-db-provider-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-for-linked-server-null   Though I note it is using MSSQL