# Import Excel Sheet into SQL Server Getting Error "The OLE DB provider “Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0” for linked server “(null)”"

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, sql-server-2008, excel-2010

When i implement this code ([Excel Sheet to Sql Server](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-and-Import-Excel-Sheet-into-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASP.Net.aspx)) Getting this Error.

**Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Unspecified error".**

I done All the Below things,

- sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
- reconfigure
- sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
- reconfigure

*Also Install 2010 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components*

Then also Same Problem.

Comment: did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572563/sql-server-cannot-initialize-the-data-source-object-of-ole-db-provider-microso?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue due to incompatibility between access diver and SQL server. I couldn't even change permission of my system.
Following is the solution that worked for me:

**Pre-Condition:**

- Office products installed is 32-bit edition.
- O/S is 64-bit.
- SQL Server installed is 64-bit edition.

**Issue:**

- Cannot execute following query:

> SELECT *
>       FROM OPENROWSET(
>           'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
>           'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Database=C:\temp\Book.xlsx',
>           'select * from [Sheet1$]')

- Following error will be displayed:

> ```
>    OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Could not find installable ISAM.".
>     Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>     Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
> ```

- This is because 64-bit MS Access driver (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.xx.x) cannot read 32-bit Excel file.

**Solution:**

1. Install 32-bit MS Access drive in passive mode in command prompt as follows:

> access_drive_path>access_dirve_name.exe /passive

```
E.g.        C:\Users\user_name\Downloads>AccessDatabaseEngine.exe /passive
```

2. Install 32-bit SQL Server (EXPRESS edition since it’s free).
3. Enable Ad Hoc Distributed queries and dynamic parameters etc. by executing the following queries:

> ```
> EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
> RECONFIGURE
> GO
> EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
> RECONFIGURE
> GO
>
> USE [master] 
> EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
> EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
> ```

4. Now try to read Excel file in SQL query **:)**

One more thing.... make sure that the file you are trying read is not opened.