# Problems with SQL Server 2005 linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, linked-server

We are trying to set an excel file as a linked server.

We have gone through not being able to use Jet, we have installed ace.

We have tried setting the Excel sheet as a datasource and using MSDASQL. We have allowed "in-process" in setting

We have played with the security settings and looked at global objects as per [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2450479)
but we are still receiving the error

[image: errormessage]

for whichever provider we use.

We are clearly doing things wrong I am not certain about security or permissions are correct

Can anybody give us some pointers or links (the server is Windows 2003 64 bit, SQL Server 2005, Excel 2003)

Many thanks

Ian

Comment: Is this not a possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441682/cannot-initialize-the-data-source-object-of-ole-db-provider-microsoft-ace-oledb?rq=1
?

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: @BaconSah I did not think so because that was 2008R2 not sql 2005 and course lots has changed between those versions

Comment: This is usually because mixing an x64 process (sqlservr) with a x86 driver (ACE). Make sure you installed the [AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)