# Not able to create MS SQL Server Linked server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, cpanel, linked-server, database-administration

I am trying to create MS SQL Server Linked server to connect web MYSQL .

I have given access to my static IP address in "Remote MYSQL"..

I have choosen following option in MS SQL Server Linked server

Provider: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers

Product name: MySQL

Data Source: MySQL ( I don't know what I should give here hence I have given MysQL)

Provider String:

> DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.5 Driver};SERVER=Shared IP address Mention in
>   CPanel;PORT=3306;DATABASE=database name; USER=user;PASSWORD=password;

When I try to connect using above obtion I am getting error as "Not able to connect"

When executed below command in my CMD
telnet "`Shared IP address Mention in CPanel`" 3306

I am getting following message:

> 5.5.5-10.0.21-MariaDBm9ï~hoqmMv?á)xF4oU

Kindly help me how to solve this issue?

Comment: http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/

Comment: I have followed your steps but still I am getting error.

Comment: what is the error...

Comment: I am getting following error "cannot initialize the data source object of ole db provider msdasql for linked server".

Comment: you dns  server is not correctly configured ... test your dns or user do not have permission on temp folder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362108/cannot-initialize-the-data-source-object-of-ole-db-provider-msdasql-for-linked

Comment: CSE_ problem solved ..?

Comment: I have tested my connection in "System DSN" it works fine but only in linked server it showing error.

Comment: I have installed latest version "Connector/ODBC 5.1.13" in my client system

Comment: have u checked permission on temp folder permission http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362108/cannot-initialize-the-data-source-object-of-ole-db-provider-msdasql-for-linked

Comment: I am using Windows 8 system in client meachine for which "temp" folder I need to change permission?

Comment: My Temp folder have full access in security Tab. But still I am not able to connect in Linkedserver

Comment: can you share exact code or screenshoot..

Comment: can you share your email id?

Comment: I have sent mail to your email id sandeepzone@gmail.com

Comment: I have given full permission to Temp folder still issue not got resolved.

I have attached screen shot of folder permission and sent to your email id.

Comment: Hi Sandeep,  Thanks for your great help. Additionally I have given provider string values like (SERVER=IPaddress;PORT=3306;DATABASE=database_name;USER=database_user;PASSWORD=database_password;" along with product name & source name while creating linked server. Now it works without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/) are step by step to create linked server to mysql .

you have to make sure that sql server service account having full [permission on temp location](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/814398) or it should be part of admin group.