# Use openrowset to read txt file in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I tried the following query:

```
select *
from openrowset('MADASQL'
               ,'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)}'
               ,'select * from C:\test.txt')
```

but it failed with an error:

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)"

So I tried:

```
SELECT  *
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\test.txt', 
                FORMATFILE= 'C:\test.xml') AS a
```

it failed with

> Cannot bulk load. The file "C:\test.txt" does not exist

I have check the path and find nothing wrong.

Comment: `C:\test.txt` is this path on server or your local machine?

Comment: Have you checked some similar questions on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362108/cannot-initialize-the-data-source-object-of-ole-db-provider-msdasql-for-linked for example?

Comment: Yes,it is on my local machine. And I have tried to restart, but still fail.

Comment: and is the SQL Server on your local machine?

Comment: Yes,they are all on my personal laptop.